# Sheets/Excel " inside ""

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, vlookup

Not sure if I correctly named (subject) this issue.

My code: `="Discount "$M4`

It doesn't work because I do not close the brackets `"` after `$M4`. But when I write `$M4"` it reopens another input for text and needs to close the bracket with another `"`.
So I tried `"""`, doesn't work either. The third bracket reopens an input too...

Anyone knows how to close a text input with a bracket in this condition, without reopening one? Thanks.

Reproducible sample:
*I do not think you need the full tables as this is only a **typo issue within the formula**, if you feel you do please ask me in the comments and I'll it.*
Full formula:

```
=IF($R$1="No",INDEX(VLOOKUP($M$2, QUERY({'Exchange Fees'!$B$2:$B, 'Exchange Fees'!$D$2:$D, 
 FILTER('Exchange Fees'!$A$2:$G, 'Exchange Fees'!$A$1:$G$1=$M4)}, 
 "select Col2,Col3 where Col1 = '"&N$2&"'", ), 2, 1)),INDEX(VLOOKUP($R$1, QUERY({'Exchange Fees'!$B$2:$B, 'Exchange Fees'!$J$2:$J, 'Exchange Fees'!$L$2:$L, 
 FILTER('Exchange Fees'!$A$2:$L, 'Exchange Fees'!$A$1:$L$1="Discount "&$M4)}, 
 "select Col2,Col3,Col4 where Col1 = '"&N$2&"'", ), 2, 0)))")))))"""
```

Comment: You say formula but `'Exchange Fees'!$A$1:$L$1="Discount "$M4` looks more like code.  Can you explain exactly what you are entering and where?

Comment: Google Sheets is not Microsoft Excel. Which of the two are you actually using?

Comment: @BigBen Google Sheets and Excel have many things in common, I know this is one of them. So this problem concerns future users of Sheets as well as Excel, I think the next ones who will have the same problem will come across this thread.

Comment: @ScottCraner cell N4 of sheet "09-2021 - Earnings", sorry

Comment: Do NOT share [spreadsheets](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455)/[images](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) as the only source of data, to avoid closure of the question. Make sure to add input and expected output as **plain text table** to the question. [Click here](//webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855) to create a table easily, which are **easier to copy/paste as well**. Also, note that [your email address can also be accessed by the public](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394304), if you share Google files.

Comment: Excel does not have the `QUERY` function. I've removed the Excel-related tags.

Comment: @BigBen okay thanks. Although, the issue is not about the `QUERY` function but the typo of formula `="Discount "$M4`. Anyway, thank you for your cooperation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
'Exchange Fees'!$A$1:$L$1="Discount "&$M4
```

---

### update:

```
=IF($R$1="No",INDEX(VLOOKUP($M$2, QUERY({'Exchange Fees'!$B$2:$B, 'Exchange Fees'!$D$2:$D, 
 FILTER('Exchange Fees'!$A$2:$G, 'Exchange Fees'!$A$1:$G$1=$M4)}, 
 "select Col2,Col3 where Col1 = '"&N$2&"'", ), 2, 1)),INDEX(VLOOKUP($R$1, QUERY({'Exchange Fees'!$B$2:$B, 'Exchange Fees'!$J$2:$J, 'Exchange Fees'!$L$2:$L, 
 FILTER('Exchange Fees'!$A$2:$L, 'Exchange Fees'!$A$1:$L$1="Discount "&$M4)}, 
 "select Col2,Col3,Col4 where Col1 = '"&N$2&"'", ), 3, 0)))
```

[image]

Comment: None of them work.

Comment: @imbehindyou can you share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output?

Comment: Thanks @player0 but the issue is that it doesn't return the good data. As you can see in your screenshot it returns "$5000 FTT Holding". Which is already what I have on my side. R1 cell is "25 FTT Staked". Therefore the vlookup should look for this in sheet 'Exchange Fees' and return the value aside. Which is: 0% cell J2.

Comment: Instead of searching in column J, it retrieves column L (of sheet 'Exchange Fees). I guess this is because the formula is not correctly taking into account the column headers: it searches for `"Discount "` in the headers but not `"Discount "&$M4`. It's not taking into account the data inside cell `M4`. I guess because the bracket closes before `$M4`.

Comment: Works wonderfully well! Thanks for the edit/update @player0!!